# Does casting actually work when done inside a function call in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, casting, virtual, base-class

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void print(void) { cout << "I am base class" << endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void print(void) { cout << "I am class B" << endl; }
};

void mainprint(A *a)
{
    (*a).print();
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    B *bp;
    A *ap;

    ap = &b;

    a.print();
    b.print();
    (*ap).print();

    bp = new B();

    mainprint((A *)bp);

    delete bp;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
I am base class
I am class B
I am class B
I am class B
```

I have casted the pointer(bp) to class A inside the function call, but it still calls the derived class print!!!

Can someone shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have casted the pointer(bp) to class A inside the function call, but it still calls the base class print!!!

I assume you mean "calls the derived class print", since that's what happened.

That's the whole point of virtual functions; the final override associated with the actual type of the object (i.e. the "dynamic type") is chosen, whatever the type of the reference or pointer used to call the function (i.e. the "static type"). So `B::print` is chosen, because `bp` still points to an instance of `B`.

If you want to force a call to `A::print`, you could do:

```
pb->A::print()
```

or, if you don't want polymorphic behaviour at all, remove the `virtual` specification.

Answer (score 3):

You have explicitly requested that behavior by making `A::print()` a [virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).

Answer (score 2):

It's virtual function dispatch (i.e. runtime polymorphism), working as intended.

One way to disable virtual function dispatch is to explicity qualify function name with class name, like this:

```
void mainprint(A *a) 
{ 
  (*a).A::print(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What were you expecting? This is how polymorphism works.

This behavior is expected and correct.

Also,

```
(*a).print();
```

is not casting, but dereferencing.

Comment: @rashid "I have casted the pointer(bp) to class A **inside** the function call"...

Comment: i meant mainprint((A *)bp); please correct me if i am confusing something.

Comment: @rashid oh ok, I must have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get where the problem is... the first one is a `print` on an actual object of type `A`, all the others are invocations of `print` over a `B` object (directly or via a pointer), so it calls `B`'s `print`.

Keep in mind that in the function call you are not casting an *object* of type `B` to an *object* of type `A` (which results in slicing), but you're just casting a pointer to it - the object itself remains intact, and thanks to virtual dispatch even if the static type of the object is `A *` the correct versions of the virtual functions are invoked.

That's how `virtual` functions work.

Comment: There is no problem, i am just trying to understand!

Comment: +1 for establishing the difference between a pointer-to-object & the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not calling the base-class print, it is calling the derived class print (I am class B) on your last call which is the correct behaviour because pointers and references work with polymorphism.

If you sliced your object then called print it would indeed print the A version. You don't want to be doing that, and fortunately you haven't.

This would be slicing:

```
B b;
A a(b); 
A a2;
a2 = b;
A& a3 = b;
b.print();
a.print();
a2.print();
a3.print();
```

and you should get:

I am class B
I am base class
I am base class
I am class B

because `a` and `a2` are both objects of type a, even though you have assigned them to b.
Slicing is not to be recommended but is a common error.

a3 however is a reference to an object of type A or one of its derivatives but is actually object b of type B and retains the polymorphic behaviour.